# #1044 error while trying to import a database through phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I keep getting the following error while trying to import my database using phpmyadmin:
[image]

Can anyone help or explain what the real problem is?
Thank you

Note: This question is about importing through phpmyadmin. You can do it from command line and with FTP. But phpmyadmin is the only way I actually know and I am trying to find an answer. Unfortunately the other question is completely different. I saw this question when I tried to write my own and thought that they were different...

Comment: If the user you are authenticated with lacks the necessary privileges to create a db, then the 1044 error follows

Comment: I didn't use phpMyAdmin for a very long time. But you probably don't have the right to create any new database on the remote server. If you want to import your tables into a given DB, then just export that tables without the database.

Comment: @Drew How is this specific question similar can you give the link to the other question.

Comment: the link is at the top of your question

Comment: I think this is the answer http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/mysql-1044-access-denied-error-message

Comment: from the dupe target, "Entering mysql without a special user is not working. Or better to say: You enter the database, but the user you use then, has nearly no rights/priviliges."

Comment: The user does not have the rights to call create database. It is pretty simple.

Comment: Hello SOLVED. Kindly read the link I gave and improvise according to your phpmyadmin version.!!!